# Mysql query on more tables

Tags: mysql

I have one table with products (zztmp_prdvz_160) and a second table with parameters (one line is one parameter), in the results I need to find products which have for example green or yellow color, and together have other parameters. I dont know how to create a select without ask to more of the same tables.

For example

```
SELECT DISTINCT pl.id_product
FROM   zztmp_prdvz_160 pl,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz0,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz1,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz2,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz3,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz4,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz5,
       zztmp_katvz_160 vz6
WHERE  pl.cena != 0
       AND vz.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz.typ = 'vzor'
       AND ( vz0.id_vzor_data = '2112'
              OR vz0.id_vzor_data = '797' )
       AND ( vz1.id_vzor_data = '1096' )
       AND ( vz2.id_vzor_data = '1132' )
       AND ( vz3.id_vzor_data = '1093' )
       AND ( vz4.id_vzor_data = '1108' )
       AND ( vz5.id_vzor_data = '35' )
       AND ( vz6.id_vzor_data = '11'
              OR vz6.id_vzor_data = '9' )
       AND vz0.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz0.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz1.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz1.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz2.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz2.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz3.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz3.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz4.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz4.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz5.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz5.typ = 'vzor'
       AND vz6.id_product = pl.id_product
       AND vz6.typ = 'vzor'
ORDER  BY pl.id_product ASC
```

Can you help me what I do wrong.

---

[Image with stucture and data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bApOk.jpg)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xb0bl.jpg)

Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zztmp_prdvz_160` (
    `id` bigint(15) NOT NULL,
      `id_product` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `datum_zm` datetime NOT NULL,
      `nazev` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
      `header` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
      `img` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
      `anotace` text,
      `volbyprd` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
      `cena` float(9,2) NOT NULL,
      `merna_jednotka` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ks',
      `vyrobce` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `typ_cen` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
      `dostupnost` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
      `skladks` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `dodaci_doba` int(3) NOT NULL,
      `cena_show_od` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_puvodni` float(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `hodnoceni` float(6,2) DEFAULT NULL,
      `specakce` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `pn` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `info_sklad_next` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `hodnota_prodej` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `hodnota_pageview` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `info_sklad` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `sort_hodnoceni` float(2,1) NOT NULL,
      `url` varchar(250) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Data for table

```
        INSERT INTO 
    `zztmp_prdvz_160` 
    (`id`, `id_product`, `datum_zm`, `nazev`, `header`, `img`, `anotace`, `volbyprd`, `cena`, `merna_jednotka`, `vyrobce`, `typ_cen`, `dostupnost`, `skladks`, `dodaci_doba`, `cena_show_od`, `cena_puvodni`, `hodnoceni`, `specakce`, `pn`, `info_sklad_next`, `hodnota_prodej`, `hodnota_pageview`, `info_sklad`, `sort_hodnoceni`, `url`) 
    VALUES
    (3, 21211, '2016-11-23 05:03:28', 'Felt SIX Pro 2012 (26)', 'Horské kolo - pánská geometrie', 'yes', 'Kola Felt řady SIX jsou předurčené pro závodní cross-country. Provedení je v různých velikostech od 15,5 do 21,5 a má pěkný design.', 'yes', 47990.00, 'ks', 'felt', 'single', 'na externím skladě', 0, 5, '', 0.00, 0.00, '', '', 5, 0, -45, 0, 0.0, '/horska-kola-hardtail/horske-kolo-felt-six-pro-2012-26');
```

Second table + data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zztmp_katvz_160` (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
      `id_vzor` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `id_vzor_data` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `id_product` int(13) NOT NULL,
      `typ` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `skladem` varchar(3) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8803 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `zztmp_katvz_160` (`id`, `id_vzor`, `id_vzor_data`, `id_product`, `typ`, `skladem`) VALUES
    (234, 102, 1092, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (235, 2, 9, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (236, 91, 796, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (237, 4, 35, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (238, 65, 324, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (239, 105, 1109, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (240, 99, 1007, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (241, 104, 1105, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (242, 107, 1132, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (243, 103, 1096, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (244, 140, 1976, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (245, 140, 1974, 21211, 'vzor', ''),
    (3323, 100000000, 3, 21211, 'stitek', ''),
    (3324, 100000000, 23, 21211, 'stitek', '');
```

Comment: What did you do wrong? I'm guessing you didn't read the help pages before posting.

Comment: Add sample data and expected output

Comment: We'll need to see the table schemas.  Where is the `color` column defined?

Comment: I added table stucture and example of data for tables.

Comment: Great. But those of us less fluent in Czech? may struggle to identify the green and yellow coloured parts of the problem !! In fact I can't find the terms 'barva', 'zelená', or 'žlutý' anywhere within the data set.

Comment: Sorry color is in this case not important. It was example. Color is in this case number. 
Product have many parametrs in table zztmp_katvz_160. One from this parametrs is color, in this case is color id_vzor:2, and red is id_vzor_data:9.

Comment: Sorry color is in this case not important. It was example. Color is in this case number. 
Product have many parametrs in table zztmp_katvz_160. One from this parametrs is color, in this case is color id_vzor:2, and red is id_vzor_data:9.
But problem is that i find product with parameters 

for example 

color: id_vzor_data:9(red) or id_vzor_data:11(green) AND  type of ride bicycles id_vzor_data:324(race) AND size of bicycles id_vzor_data:1007(29 inches) ... etc.

I have problem that I dont how how make SQL without request on more same tables :(